# How to find the partition by ROWID in oracle?

Tags: oracle, partition, rowid

I created the partitions for the table (test) by Hijri months (date) ,
 How to match a particular partition by ROWID in oracle?

Comment: you can extract file_id and block_id from ROWID (by calling some dbms_package). Then you can find the "closest" extent header by querying dba_extents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite straightforward, using DBMS_RowID and dba_objects.

```
select *
from   dba_objects
where  data_object_id = dbms_rowid.rowid_object(ROWID_OF_THE_ROW)
```

Further tips and observations here: https://oraclesponge.wordpress.com/2006/05/11/getting-the-subpartition-name-for-a-row/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT dbms_rowid.rowid_object(ROWID) data_object_id
FROM test;
```

To get the partition name you can use

```
SELECT partition_name 
from user_tab_partitions
where table_name='test'
```

Comment: how I can get the name of the partition?

Comment: @mohsen.noor:- Updated my answer. Please check!

Comment: I want to give Rowid and oracle returns to me partition
My record belongs to which partition 
SELECT partition_name 
from user_tab_partitions -- I don't know which table it is?
where ROWID = 'xxx'

Answer (score 1):

```
select object_name tab_name, subobject_name parttition   from user_objects where object_id =dbms_rowid.rowid_object('xxxxx');
```